# Refer cell range from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I got stuck on how to implement the logic dynamically.

i'm referencing the source sheet to main page sheet for the cells ranging from c5 to c12, similarly for other cells, eg. n5 to n12.

````
Sub cellRef()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HR - Source")
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HR - Main Page")
 destSht.Range("C5").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!C5"
 destSht.Range("C6").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!C6"
 destSht.Range("C7").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!C7"
 destSht.Range("C8").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!C8"
 destSht.Range("C11").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!C11"
 destSht.Range("C12").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!C12"
 destSht.Range("N5").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!N5"
 destSht.Range("N6").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!N6"
 destSht.Range("N7").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!N7"
 destSht.Range("N8").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!N8"
 destSht.Range("N11").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!N11"
 destSht.Range("N12").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!N12"
 destSht.Range("M5").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!M5"
 destSht.Range("M6").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!M6"
 destSht.Range("M7").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!M7"
 destSht.Range("M8").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!M8"
 destSht.Range("M11").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!M11"
 destSht.Range("M12").Formula = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!M12"
 
 end sub```

how to make it dynamic, using any loops?
please suggest.
````

Comment: what do you mean with dynamic?

Comment: Just fill C5, N5 and M5. Then use range("C5:C12").FillDown

Comment: instead of adding c5,c6,c7 can i use looping. i have values from c5:N67

Comment: I'm new to this, could you please give me the formula to use, @Andreas

Comment: `destSht.Range("C5:C8,C11:C12,N5:N8,N11:N12,M5:M8,M11:M12").FormulaR1C1 = "='" & srcSht.Name & "'!RC"` would be one way

Comment: i have values of C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L. WHEN I TRIED , IT IS FAILING AT F

Comment: C5:C8,C11:C15,C17:C23,C25:C29,C32:C34,C36:C48,C50:C60,C62:C64,C66:C67,D5:D8,D11:D15,D17:D23,D25:D29,D32:D34,D36:D48,D50:D60,D62:D64,D66:D67,E5:E8,E11:E15,E17:E23,E25:E29,E32:E34,E36:E48,E50:E60,E62:E64,E66:E67,F5:F8,F11:F15,F17:F23,F25:F29,F32:F34,F36:F48,F50:F60,F62:F64,F66:F67,G5:G8,G11:G15,G17:G23,G25:G29,G32:G34,G36:G48,G50:G60,G62:G64,G66:G67,H5:H8,H11:H15,H17:H23,H25:H29,H32:H34,H36:H48,H50:H60,H62:H64,H66:H67,I5:I8,I11:I15,I17:I23,I25:I29,I32:I34,I36:I48,I50:I60,I62:I64,I66:I67,J5:J8,J11:J15,J17:J23,J25:J29,J32:J34,J36:J48,J50:J60,J62:J64,J66:J67,K5:K8,K11:K15,K17:K23,K25:K29,K32:K34,..

Comment: You can have a maximum address length of 255 characters for the `Range` property, so you'll need to split it up into a few lines.

Comment: Thanks. i did it